# Создать паттерн для удаления лишних знаков в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно очистить строку ввода пользователя от лишних символов.
В строке пользователем будет формироваться новый #tag для сообщения, и в нем не нужны символы такие как

```
, . ; " ' ` {} [] <> # ^ @ :
```

нашел такой вариант:

```js
var s = "#строка{[]} * &!? <:> \"569-35* ` с $ ^символами ;буквами, ' и @~цифрами";
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
console.log("исходная: "+s);
console.log("результат: "+punctuationless);
```

но он не полностью удовлетворяет необходимым мне условиям и заменяет символы на пробел, а не убирает его.
Я не силен в регулярках, буду благодарен за помощь в составлении нужной или коррекции примера выше.

Ну или как вариант можно просто оставить буквы-цифры, пробел, символ подчеркивания и тире, удалив все остальное.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = "#строка{[]} * &!? <:> \"569-35* ` с $ ^символами ;буквами, ' и @~цифрами";
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[^\wа-яё]/gi,"");
console.log("исходная: "+s);
console.log("результат: "+punctuationless);
```

Answer (score 2):

Пробелы наверное все же подчистить надо а не удалить.

UPD: сразу не заметил про дефис `\-`

```js
var string = "#string__строка{[]} * &!? <:> \"569-35* ` с $ ^символами тире - ;буквами, ' и @~цифрами";

console.log( string.replace( /[^\w\sа-я\-]+/gi, '' ) );
// Пробелы как я понимаю все-таки оставлять нужно
console.log( string.replace( /[^\w\sа-я\-]+/gi, '' ).replace( /\s+/g, ' ' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Символы нужно экранировать, а так ваша функция все хорошо делает, и она не заменяет на пробел, а удаляет. Вторая функция заменяет от одного до нескольких пробелов на один.

```js
var s = "#строка{[]} * &!? # <:> \"569-35* ` с $ ()^символами ;буквами, '~_={}и @~цифрами";
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/\[\]\<\>\#!\$%\^&\*;:\{\}=\-\_`\@\~\(\)]/g,"");
var test = punctuationless.replace(/ {1,}/g," ");
console.log("исходная: "+ s);
console.log("результат: "+ punctuationless);
console.log("результа2: "+ test);
```